# SQLAlchemy exclude_properties not working in Declarative

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In declarative approach, I want to exclude one property, its working properly when my column name and property name are same. But if I give different name then its not working.
Here is my sample code.

```
Base = declarative_base() 
class tblUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tblUser'
    User_Id = Column('User_Id', String(100), primary_key=True)
    SequenceNo = Column('Sequence_No', Integer)
    FullName = Column('FullName', String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {'exclude_properties' :['Sequence_No']}

user = tblUser()
user.User_Id = '1000001'
user.SequenceNo = 101
session.add(user)
session.commit()
```

In the above sample I don't want the SequenceNo property to be updated in database even if I assign some value to it. So I used exclude_properties but still its updating the value in db. But if I change the property name from SequenceNo to Sequence_No (same as the column name) then its working as per the behaviour. Can anyone help me?

Thanks
Adhi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `__mapper_args__` is probably the wrong approach. It is intended to control the reflection of an existing database table into a mapper, not make a column 'read-only'.

I think a better approach would be to use a [hybrid property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

Base = declarative_base() 
class tblUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tblUser'
    User_Id = Column('User_Id', String(100), primary_key=True)
    FullName = Column('FullName', String(50))

    _Sequence_No = Column('Sequence_No', Integer)
    _local_Sequence_No = None

    @hybrid_property
    @property
    def SequenceNo(self):
        if self._local_Sequence_No is not None:
            return self._local_Sequence_No
        return self._SequenceNo

    @SequenceNo.setter
    def SequenceNo(self, value):
        self._local_Sequence_No = value
```

The original `Sequence_No` column is available via a private attribute, and the `SequenceNo` property intercepts writes and stores them on the instance to be re-used later, but not written to the database.

Comment: Yes. I already tried that. I tried by giving ['SequenceNo'] and  [SequenceNo]. But still its not working.

Comment: @Adhi: Feared it might. The `__mapper_args__` attribute is meant for reflecting existing tables, not for defining items on your schema. I'll update the answer to suggest a different approach.

Comment: Hi Martijn, Thanks a lot. This what I want exactly. I'll try this.

Comment: Hi this works for normal insert, read and query. But I altered the Sequence_No column as Auto_Increment column (in MySQL backend). Now the problem is after I issue session.commit() the value generated at the backend for Sequence_No column not reflecting in the property SequenceNo in the same session. But if I declared Sequence_No as PrimaryKey SQLAlchemy takes care of loading the value form db after the value is generated. Is there a way to do this for non-Primary Key property?